# Sorting bars in bar graph according to auxiliary variable

Tags: graph, stata

I would like to draw a bar plot with percentages of some characteristics of my sample.

Within the bar graph, I would like to order the bars by an auxiliary variable. This auxiliary variable classifies the variable into subcategories.

According to my reading of the Stata documentation this should be easily done using something like:

```
graph bar, over(group, sort(sortvar))
```

However, I get an error message:

> variable mean not found r(111);

This is puzzling to me. What am I doing wrong?

Is there maybe a workaround using `graph bar (asis)` or another solution?

Here is a syntax example which should reproduce the problem:

```
// Load example data
sysuse nlsw88

// Generate auxiliary variable: Blue collar occupations 
gen bluecol = cond(inrange(occupation, 5,8), 0, 1)

// Bar plot of occupational distribution sorted first by blue collar vs. non-blue collar (and second by numeric values)
graph hbar, over(occupation, sort(bluecol)) name(sortauxvar)
```

I am using Stata 15.1 (Revision 06 Jun 2018).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not seem to have any *yvars* specified in your `graph hbar` command.

The following works for me:

```
graph hbar (percent) age, over(occupation, sort(bluecol)) name(sortauxvar)
```

Type `help graph bar` for full syntax.

Comment: Many thanks! This seems to solve the problem. I did not use _yvars_ since Stata 13-something made it superfluous to always specify them. The help file states "yvars is optional if the option over(varname) is specified". In this case, it seems necessary though.